# Static functions/subs vs static variables

Tags: vba

What would be an underlying difference in the following aspects of the ensuing two subs:

1. Scope of the subs?  (This question primarily applies to the second
   routine)
2. Scope of the variable declarations within?
3. Application of one vs another?

## 1:

```
Sub test1()
    Static x As Byte
    x = 1
End Sub
```

## 2:

```
Static Sub test2()
    Dim y As Byte
    y = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: Both local scope for variable x. Both subs can be called from anywhere in project I believe. Also appears to be no difference in whether you can alter the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the entire procedure `Static` is a shortcut for [declaring all its local variables `Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement).

So there is effectively no difference between the subs, because effectively all their local variables are declared as `Static` and as such are [preserved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) between the calls.

But as in both subs you manually overwrite the value to something else right after the variable declaration, the effect of preserving the value does nothing for you.

There is no difference in the scope of the subs (it remains what it was before `Static`), or the the scope of the local variables (they remain local).

Comment: Nice answer. Could you expand more on when either option is useful in application?

Comment: @GSerg for the purpose of this question, you are absolutely correct. The overwriting of the values was completely unnecessary.  Nevertheless, great answer, thank you kindly!

Comment: Here is an example of using static variables in recursion. https://pastebin.com/BfvdFkBq The alternative is to pass the static variables as parameters - but this was easy.